# Meaning of "float a deadpoint"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, terminology

In a book about climbing technique (written by an American) I found the following expression:

> ...: floating a deadpoint from any one of a million different body positions.

While the meaning of any single word in the sentence is clear, I don't understand what "floating a deadpoint" means.

Comment: I am a native speaker of American English, and I have no idea what the word "deadpoint" means.  I don't think I've ever encountered it before.  I therefore strongly suspect that this phrase is climbing jargon, not American English.

Comment: Checkout [this blog post](http://adam.younglogic.com/2008/03/deadpoint/) about climbing

Comment: Also, any posters here might want to submit a [DMCA takedown notice to Google](http://www.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=lr_dmca&product=blogger) over [this other blog](http://englishqna.blogspot.com/2011/12/meaning-of-float-deadpoint.html) using your material without permission

Comment: @MattЭллен Oh dear Lord! That is appalling. That website http://englishqna.blogspot.com/ has verbatim copied over 4,300 entries from English StackExchange! If it is allowed to remain as is, and continue, then it sets precedent for identical behavior for others, to repeat for any other SE website, no?

Comment: @FeralOink: Aye, but as far as I know you can only submit DMCA reports for your own content, not for the site as a whole. [This question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2152) on meta goes into more detail

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications! Also the draw in the blog posted by @matt is an answer by his own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to make your body move when it has no momentum whatsoever, with all the parts of the body being absolutely still and calm, no matter what its current position is.

Comment: That sounds like it implies a _static_ move in climbing terms though, whereas deadpointing implies a dynamic move, timed for the moment of zero momentum.